# volume of a truncated cone that is not a frustum

Tags: geometry, volume

I know the formula for a conical frustum is

$$\frac{\pi h}{3}\left( r^2+rR+R^2 \right) $$

What would the formula be for the area of a truncated right circular cone be where the top is not parallel to the base.

With the plane truncating the cone at an angle $\theta$ from parallel and $\theta <.5 \pi$.

Comment: I think that would depend on the plane secting the cone. Just the fact that the basis could be an ellipse, hyperbola or parabola leads me to think that there would be no nice general formula like the one for the frustum.  
Having the equation of the plane and of the cone you could calculate the volume through integration. The solution is something that depends on the coefficient of the plane.

Comment: It should only result in an ellipse on the top an a circle on the bottom.

Comment: Well, yes, unless you also cut part of the basis. Anyway, the solution will depend on the coefficients of the plane. You could try to make a general integration and see what you get.

Comment: I don't know integration yet . but there should be a formula for a cone truncated by a plane at an angle $\theta$ from parallel where $\theta <.5 \pi$

Comment: If the cutting plane $P$ lies at perpendicular distance $d$ from the vertex of the cone, and if $P$ cuts the cone in an ellipse with semi-axes $a$ and $b$, the volume is $\frac{1}{3} \pi abd$. It's not difficult to express this in terms of the half-angle $\phi$ of the vertex and the angle $\theta < \frac{1}{2}\pi - \phi$ between $P$ and the base of the circular cone. (If $\theta \geq \frac{1}{2}\pi - \phi$, the volume is infinite.)

Comment: Very nice, I didn't think about it: the remaining part is an "oblique cone" with elliptical base. You should make an answer. I'd like to +1 that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plane that meets one nappe of a right circular cone in an ellipse defines an oblique cone with an elliptical base. If the plane lies at distance $d$ from the cone's vertex, and if the base has semi-axes $a$ and $b$, the volume is $\frac{1}{3} \pi abd$.

If the cone has vertex half-angle $\phi$, the cutting plane crosses the cone axis at distance $h$ from the vertex, and the cutting plane makes angle $\theta$ with the flat base, with $0 \leq \theta < \frac{\pi}{2} - \phi$, then the volume of the truncated cone is
$$
\frac{\pi}{3}\, \frac{h^{3} \cot\phi}{(\cot^{2} \phi - \tan^{2} \theta)^{3/2}}.
$$
(If $\theta \geq \frac{\pi}{2} - \phi$, the volume is infinite.)

[image: A cone cut by a slant plane]

For brevity, let $k = \cot\phi$ denote the slope of the cone generator and $m = \tan\theta$ denote the slope of the cutting plane.

In Cartesian coordinates with the vertex at the origin and the cone opening around the positive $z$-axis, the cone and cutting plane have respective equations
\begin{align*}
  z^{2} &= k^{2}(x^{2} + y^{2}),
  \tag{1a} \\
  z &= mx + h.
  \tag{1b}
\end{align*}
The plane and cone meet where $k^{2}(x^{2} + y^{2}) = z^{2} = (mx + h)^{2}$, or
$$
(k^{2} - m^{2}) x^{2} - 2mhx - h^{2} + k^{2} y^{2} = 0.
\tag{2}
$$
(This is the equation of the elliptical "shadow" of the base, which does not directly give the shape of the base.)

In the longitudinal plane $y = 0$ (shown), the cone and cutting plane meet when
$$
(k^{2} - m^{2}) x^{2} - 2mhx - h^{2} = 0.
$$
The quadratic formula gives the roots
$$
x_{\pm} = \frac{h(m \pm k)}{k^{2} - m^{2}}.
\tag{3}
$$
The semi-major axis is the distance between the corresponding points on the cone,
$$
a = \tfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{1 + m^{2}}(x_{+} - x_{-})
= \sqrt{1 + m^{2}}\, \frac{hk}{k^{2} - m^{2}}
= \sec\theta\, \frac{hk}{k^{2} - m^{2}}.
\tag{4a}
$$
The semi-minor axis of the slant base is the semi-minor axis of the ellipse (2), namely the positive value of $y$ in equation (2) when
$$
x = \frac{x_{-} + x_{+}}{2} = \frac{hm}{k^{2} - m^{2}}.
$$
For this $x$, we have $mx + h = \dfrac{hk^{2}}{k^{2} - m^{2}}$, so
\begin{align*}
  y^{2} &= \frac{1}{k^{2}} \bigl[(mx + h)^{2} - k^{2} x^{2}\bigr] \\
  &= \frac{1}{k^{2}} \left[\frac{h^{2} k^{4}}{(k^{2} - m^{2})^{2}} - \frac{k^{2} h^{2} m^{2}}{(k^{2} - m^{2})^{2}}\right] \\
  &= \frac{h^{2}}{k^{2} - m^{2}}.
\end{align*}
The semi-minor axis is therefore
$$
b = \frac{h}{\sqrt{k^{2} - m^{2}}}.
\tag{4b}
$$
Trigonometry shows the distance from the vertex to the cutting plane is $d = h\cos\theta$. Combining with equations (4a) and (4b), the volume of the slant cone is
$$
\frac{\pi}{3} abd
= \frac{\pi}{3} \left(\sec\theta\, \frac{hk}{k^{2} - m^{2}}\right) \frac{h}{\sqrt{k^{2} - m^{2}}}\, (h\cos\theta)
= \frac{\pi}{3}\, \frac{h^{3} k}{(k^{2} - m^{2})^{3/2}},
$$
as claimed.

Comment: so is $ H - R \tan \theta = h $ if the plane intersects the base of the cone a exactly one point and H is the height of the cone and R the radius of the base

Comment: Yes: If a (flat-base) circular cone of height $H$ and radius $R$ is cut by a slant plane at angle $\theta$ so that the cut just touches the base (on the right side in the diagram), then substituting$$k = \frac{H}{R},\qquad h = H - mR$$expresses the volume in terms of $H$, $R$, and $\theta$: $$\text{volume} = \frac{\pi R^{2} H}{3}\left(\frac{H - mR}{H + mR}\right)^{3/2}.$$

Comment: and if I also wanted to remove a cone with a base parallel to the original where this cone may or may not overlap the part excluded when making the first truncation

Comment: Truncating by two planes that do not cross inside the cone is an easy extension: Just calculate the difference of volumes of slant cones. Handling the situation where the cutting planes cross inside the cone is another matter entirely. If you're more than casually interested (there is not going to be a nice formula), I suggest posting a separate question.

Comment: ok I added a question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074126/volume-of-a-truncated-conical-frustum)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer using a double integral. I use the same set up and notation as in Andrew D. Hwang's answer, but in cylindrical coordinates.

The equation of the cone is $z = kr$; of the plane, $z = m r \cos\theta + h$; and therefore of the elliptical shadow, $r = h/(k - m\cos\theta)$. Then the volume is\begin{align}
& \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{h/(k - m\cos\theta)} (z_\text{plane} - z_\text{cone})r\,dr\,d\theta\\
& = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{h/(k - m\cos\theta)} (m r \cos\theta + h - kr)r\,dr\,d\theta\\
& = \frac{h^3}6 \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{(k - m \cos\theta)^2}\\
& = \frac{h^3}6 \frac{2 \pi k}{(k^2 - m^2)^{3/2}}\\
& = \frac{\pi h^3 k}{3(k^2 - m^2)^{3/2}}.\end{align}
For the second integration, see [How to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{(A+B\cos\theta)^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331632/how-to-evaluate-int-02-pi-fracd-thetaab-cos-theta2)